# Ubuntu 20.04 static route on netplan without gateway address

Tags: networking, server, netplan

I am routing virtual machine's IP through the host (I have my reasons).

```
ip a a 172.16.0.50/32 dev ens3 (VM's main IP)
```

I add routes for routing packets to the host's main IP (which acts as a router):

```
ip route add 192.168.50.10/32 dev ens3 (Specifying that host IP is reachable from interface)
ip route add default via 192.168.50.10 dev ens3 (Specifying that host IP is the gateway)
```

Now everything works correctly like this, however, after reboot I have to add these routes to "rc.local" for them to be run. Is it possible to set up routes on netplan without specifying the gateway address on "via" option since I use the interface as a gateway? If I restart the network service I have to re-run "rc.local".

I am talking about this command, in particular, being in netplan:

```
ip route add 192.168.50.10/32 dev ens3
```

Comment: Ubuntu 20?  There is no such release. Ubuntu uses *yy.mm* format (year.month of release) for all server & desktop releases, the *yy* being used only for IoT and specialist appliance/devices or cloud use releases than can use *snap* packages only.  Please clarify you release

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The netplan syntax you're looking for is `on-link: true`.

Comment: Excellent. Thank you. Apparently, it is also acceptable to use `scope: link`

Comment: thanks **so** much! after 2h of searching why the route was never there...